# Saving an output as .txt file from for-loop for a function

Tags: python, for-loop

I am a beginner in python and trying to save these the output for loop calculation to a .txt file.

I have an input data with 40 columns and 300 rows.  I am putting sample data:

```
4.3 3.4 2.3
8.5 1.0 0.0
2.4 4.2 4.5
3.9 2.1 0.5

import numpy as np

q = np.loadtxt('test.txt')

def qtot(i):
    total = 0
    for j in range (3):
        total += q[i][j]
    return total
```

I would like to save `qtot` into an output file.
Any help would be truly appreciated.

Comment: qtot is a fucntion. Do you mean that you would like to save total to a text file?

Comment: @Rob, from the sample data, I will get four numbers for `qtot` if I called them `qtot(0), .... qtot(4)`  I would like to save it to a  text file.  I do not want to do it for 300 numbers.  I am planning to graph the data.

Comment: I dont use numpy but I believe its something like: q.savetxt("filename.txt", total)

Comment: You can get the `total` then write it as a comma-separated string in an output file like `with open('output.txt', 'w') as f: f.write(",".join(str(t) for t in total))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have read your 300 lines file into memory and it is a numpy array. Let's do your simple computation inside numpy and use it to save everything into a text file.

```
import numpy as np
np.savetxt("output.txt", np.sum( np.loadtxt('test.txt'),axis=1 )[0:5] )
```

How does it work.....

1. np.load - loads the file and it is 2d array
2. np.sum  - sums elements in the array, but axis=1 tells numpy that sum should go in raws so it returns an array with the same number of elements as lines in your file
3. [0:5]   - cuts down this array to just the first five elements. You can use slices or tuples to cut required lines from the array
4. np.savetxt - saves it into a file

Note that numpy does everything in low-level c-like code. So summing by raw for all 300 lines will be faster than a loop in python.

--ADD--

If you want to add your results to the file, you should open it in the append mode:

```
with open(output_file, "a") as fd:
   np.savetxt(fd, np.sum( np.loadtxt('test.txt'),axis=1 )[0:5] )
```

but if you want to process multiple files inside the same run, it is better to accumulate results in the memory and save once

```
result = []
for fname in [list of input files]:
   result.append( np.sum( np.loadtxt(fname),axis=1 )[0:5] )
np.saavetxt("output.txt", np.array(result))
```

Comment: instead of saving it as a .txt file, can you save this as an array?

Comment: What do you mean? If you will read the resulted file by `np.loatxt`, it is an array.

Comment: I am planning to do this five times for five different files. But I want to save it all together as one file.

Comment: Are you going to run the program 5 times, so result should accumulate in the file, or you whant to do it 5 times in the one run?

Comment: I want to run it 5 times in one run and save it in one file with five columns